# Simplest method(s) in R for separating out each value from "select all that apply" question and including sum in descriptive table?

Tags: r, data-analysis, survey, separator, qualtrics

Admittedly, I'm very new to R and data analysis in general. So, please forgive me if this either makes no sense or if it's elementary in nature.

My dataset is comprised of responses to a survey distributed to U.S. states (i.e., one response per state). I want to create a table with some simple descriptive statistics, like observations and percentages. Although I thought this would be pretty straightforward, I'm having a difficult time effectively incorporating data from a select variable.

The survey question presented respondents with various elements of a drafted management plan and asked them to select any of the listed elements featured in their own plans.

Example of choices:

1. Prevention / Risk minimization
2. Response / Management
3. Surveillance
4. Other
5. Our agency does not have a written plan

However, when multiple options were chosen, the data frame listed the entire combination selected in a single cell. Thus, if I used that variable column in a table, it lists the number of observations with each unique combination of selections given.

What I'm looking for (if possible) is a table that lists each choice item individually and gives the count of how many times it was selected by respondents.

I've tried a number of things and had some limited success, but not in a way that's allowed me to incorporate this into a single table. It's either given me a separate data frame that has a mismatching number of rows or an error.

```
table2 <- abc[,c('Region','CWD.Detected','Elements.of.Written.CWD.Plan')]
tbl_summary(table2)`
```

[Elements of Written Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxpc2.png)

While I did find a way to produce a tally of the information I'm hoping to include, I haven't found a way to incorporate it back into that same table.

```
x <- abc %>%
  separate_rows(Elements.of.Written.CWD.Plan, sep = ',') %>%
  group_by(Elements.of.Written.CWD.Plan) %>% 
  tally()

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  Elements.of.Written.CWD.Plan                    n
  <chr>                                       <int>
1 Other (Please specify)                         11
2 Our agency does not have a written CWD plan     4
3 Prevention/risk minimization                   36
4 Response/management                            40
5 Surveillance                                   37
```

Comment: Please add an example of your desired output. As it stands ,it's not clear where you want the values from "x" to be added. Thanks

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example